# "sudo nautilus" does not allow changing files or folders

Tags: sudo, ubuntu-12.04

I can't modify files in Ubuntu 12.04. I'm trying to change the permissions so that I can add a folder or change a file and all I get is this:

```
$ sudo nautilus
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must only be writeable by owner   
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugin
```

Comment: Watch the language please

Comment: What are the current permissions for **/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so**?

Answer (score 3):

Try `gksudo nautilus` instead.

From [RootSudo - Community Ubuntu Documentation # Graphical Sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical%20sudo):

> You should **never** use normal sudo to start graphical applications as Root. You should use `gksudo` (`kdesudo` on Kubuntu) to run such programs. gksudo sets HOME=~root, and copies .Xauthority to a tmp directory. This prevents files in your home directory becoming owned by Root. (AFAICT, this is all that's special about the environment of the started process with `gksudo` vs. `sudo`).

Comment: I assume `nautalis` is a typo.

Comment: nope and nope still doesn't work the entire sudo suit doesn't work not even su. It's something to do with he permissions but without sudo it's almost impossible to change :S any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the error message is accurate, and that you can gain access to root, then you should do what the message says and add write permissions to the file:

```
~# chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

Alternatively, you can force a re-installation of sudo, which will reset the permissions on the files in that package:

```
~# aptitude reinstall sudo
```

If you don't have access to root via *su*, you can try booting into single user mode, or a chroot into your system with a recovery CD in order to effect repairs. You will definitely need *some* means of gaining root permissions to fix your problem, though.

Comment: Operation not permitted
and 
aptitude is not installed therefore need sudo to install it ?

Comment: and the only other problem is that I'm using virtual box how do I boot into single user mode?

Comment: @AaronBishop: At the GRUB boot loader prompt, scroll down to the "Recovery" option. This will boot you into a root terminal, or a curses menu form which you can continue into the root terminal (depending on the distro/release). Then retry @CodeGnome's `chmod` command. Reboot and repent.

Answer (score 0):

try `su -` then press enter then enter password, hope this will also work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Under Ubuntu, try

```
sudo -i
```

Enter your password, then

```
gksu nautilus
```

Nautilus will open and allow changes to folders and files.

Comment: The problem is that `sudo` itself refuses to execute, since one of its shared libs is/may be world-writable, thus weakening its security.