# gksudo nautilus doesn't work. Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu, ssl, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to open my /etc/apache2 folder through terminal. I tried running `gksudo nautilus` and `gksu nautilus`. Both doesn't show anything and do not show any errors in terminal. But `nautilus` works fine with out `sudo`.

I have tried the solution in here [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1503801) but still cannot make it work. Running `sudo mkdir /root/.config/nautilus` also tells that folder already exists.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can try copying .config/nautilus/desktop-metadata file to /root/.config/nautilus location not sure whether it work or not because in my system(ubuntu 12.04) does'nt observing any issue like that.
You can also look on 
[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201030/gksu-not-working)

or [2](https://superuser.com/questions/424597/sudo-nautilus-does-not-allow-changing-files-or-folders)
or [3](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1677904)

Comment: thanks for the answer. The problem is I cannot open root directory without sudo. It say I have no permission to open that directory.